# Building of Blender 2.73 as python module fails

Tags: python, versions

Currently, I'm trying to build the latest Git version of Blender 2.73 as python module under Windows, like described here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule. Finally, I want to use the python module together with an appropriate Python IDE, like PyCharm for example.

I've tried both the compilation with mingw64_gcc49 and the compilation with win64_vc12. With both toolchains I've came up with the following build error:

```
Error   44  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'utfconv.h': No such file or directory   blender-dev\blender\intern\ghost\intern\GHOST_SystemPathsWin32.cpp  38
```

This leads to the problem that it is not able to build/link:

```
Error   141 error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\bf_intern_ghost.lib'   blender-dev\blender-build-win64_vc12\source\creator\LINK
```

For building blender, I just followed the detailed wiki guide.
It seems that there had been a similar bug in the past, like I figured out reading this mailing list: http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-python/2012-June/005887.html

It would be great if somebody can point me into the right direction for solving this.

Comment: I have this problem too. I manually add the blender/intern/utfconv to header search path. And after that you may need to define WITH_INPUT_IME too(/D "WITH_INPUT_IME" if you are using Visual C++). I am afraid there is something wrong with our config/build process since the build bot for the official release does not encounter these problems.

Comment: Blender.stackexchange is for blender user questions, as a programming question it is more suited to [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com). For help compiling blender [#blendercoders or #blendercompilers on IRC](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Community:Chat) would be your best option. Looks like your on windows - do you have [these libs from svn](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BL/browse/trunk/lib/windows_vc12/)? Can you [build a normal copy of blender](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Windows)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I followed the suggestion of @TheBusyTypist and it worked for me that way. I wasn't sure where it would fit better, thanks for pointing that out. My next question related to building blender will go into stackoverflow.com.